# Creating a Simple One-Field Form to Build an Object of Names in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Beginner here. I've tried a few things and have come across a few pretty complex answers to similar questions, but is there a simple way to do this? I kind of managed to get it to work, but it just continues to overwrite the first entry. 
Thanks.

```
<h1>meal calculator</h1>

<div id='dinerForm'>
    <label>What are the names of the diners?<input type='text' id='dinerName'></label>
    <button type="button" onclick="buildDinerList()">Add to List</button>
</div>
<script>

//I'd like to be able to enter the names of the people in my party, ie., all diners
var dinerList = {};
function buildDinerList() {
dinerList.dinerName = document.getElementById('dinerName').value;
};

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a bit unclear what you are asking, some example output would be helpful. You initialized `dinerList` to be an object, but named it and talk about it as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Object  values are expected to be **name:value** pairs `dinerList.dinerName` sets the value of `dinerName` within your `dinerList` **object**.

`dinerList` looks like this `{dinerName : 'value'}` and everytime run your function the value of `dinerName` is updated.

Unless you're passing a new **Property** along with the dinner's name (the **Property Value**) then
what you're after is an **Array** where `dinerList` looks like `['Mike', 'james', Mary']` like so:

`var dinerList = [];
function buildDinerList() {
dinerList.push(document.getElementById('dinerName').value);
}`

`array.push()` adds an element to the end of the array.